# Multiplying number from XML gets rounded

Tags: php, xml, rounding

I am pulling an exchange rate from yahoo's xml (euros to dollars)
I think need to multiply the rate by a dynamic value. However, the rate I am pulling is not multiplying correctly.

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20%28%22EURUSD%22%29&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys") or die();

foreach ($xml->results->rate as $item){
    $EUR2USD = $item->Rate;
}

echo $EUR2USD*2;        // Gives me what looks like a rounded number "2"
echo 1.2475*2;          // When I put in the rate by hand (1.2475) multiplication works = "2.495"
?>
```

Why is this simple math not working?

EDIT - ADDING XML

```
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:count="1" yahoo:created="2014-11-27T11:45:32Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
    <results>
        <rate id="EURUSD">
            <Name>EUR to USD</Name>
            <Rate>1.2482</Rate>
            <Date>11/27/2014</Date>
            <Time>6:44am</Time>
            <Ask>1.2483</Ask>
            <Bid>1.2481</Bid>
        </rate>
    </results>
</query>
```

Comment: What does the data you're pulling in look like?  Try var_dumping $item->Rate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've almost certainly run into a type-juggling anomaly.  PHP sees you're trying to multiply a string and attempts to cast it into a type that can be multiplied.  In its infinite wisdom, it is for some reason casting the string to an integer.

You should never rely on PHP's type juggling to do the right thing because in the rare cases when it doesn't, it will produce some very unpredictable results.  Instead, you should explicitly cast the input data

```
$EUR2USD = (float) $item->Rate;
```

or

```
$EUR2USD = floatval ($item->Rate);
```

Comment: How frustrating. Thanks!